# Pandas merge other than equal

Tags: python, pandas

df1:

```
 Con1   Con2    Con3
 p      s       100
 q      t       200
 p      t       300
 q      s       400
```

df2:

```
Ton1    Ton2    Ton3
p       s       150
p       t       110
p       s       108
q       t       409
q       s       410
q       t       406
```

The output should be:

```
Con1    Con2    Con3    Ton1    Ton2    Ton3
p       s       100     p       s       108
q       t       200     Nan     Nan     Nan
p       t       300     Nan     Nan     Nan
q       s       400     Nan     Nan     Nan
```

Merge should be based on logic Ton3 should be 6-10% higher than Con3

**Logic: (Ton3 => (6%*Con3) +Con3) & (Ton3 =< (10%*Con3) +Con3)**

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=['Con1','Con2']+logic, right_on=['Ton1','Ton2']+logic, how='left')
```

Comment: I would suggest you to include data , so others could reproduce it , instead of including image.

Comment: Would keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame Generation

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Con1':['p','q','p','q'], 'Con2':['s','t','t','s'], 'Con3':[100,200,300,400]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ton1':['p','p','p','q','q','q'], 'Ton2':['s','t','s','t','s','t'], 'Ton3':[150,110,108,409,410,406]})
```

Merging dataframes and applying given  conditions:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on=['Con1','Con2'], right_on=['Ton1','Ton2'])
df = df[(df['Ton3']>=((0.06*df['Con3']) +df['Con3'])) & (df['Ton3']<=((0.1*df['Con3']) +df['Con3']))]
print(df)
```

I think this should be the final format of output. 
Also note that , for a particular pair of **Con1** and **Con2** in **df1**, there could be multiple pairs of **Ton1** and **Ton2** in df2.

And if you must have to get rows with NaN too, run this block of code after running upper blocks

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df,how='left',left_on=['Con1','Con2','Con3'], right_on=['Con1','Con2','Con3'])
print(df)
```

Comment: I understood your point of first merging the data frame and then putting the condition seprately. Thanks mate :)